# Please explain to me this merge with git

Tags: git

[image]

Considering:

the hash d0b3583 is an update to version 0.1.6 and

the hash 7648a5e is and update to version 0.1.7

the merge in ecdcbcb is saying on version 0.1.7 the author merge the again 0.1.6 ? am i correct?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do `git merge --no-ff` it will always create merge commit with two parents even in case it could fast forward and just pick a commit. This might be the your case.

Comment: Where can you see two parents ? (Ok, at the side of "merge:" ) Are you saying now the head contains commits from 0.1.6 AND 0.1.7 ?

Comment: Because commit d0b3583 (v0.1.6) is a parent of 7648a5e (0.1.7), 7648a5e already contains all the changes from d0b3583. The contents of the merge commit ecdcbc is probably identical to 7648a5e, but it was created with two parents because of `git merge --no-ff`.